# Fastest .htaccess redirect from example.com to www.example.com?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, performance, no-www

Now using the standard cPanel-created Apache .htaccess redirect, but it's taking a full 2 seconds to go from ´example.com´ to ´www.example.com´.

Is there a faster method? Or should I let go of the redirect as this is purely for cosmetic/uniformity/branding?

Comment: Show the .htaccess file it created so we can review it

Comment: The cPanel generated .htaccess redirect is often very "ugly" and can sometimes not work as intended. However, if this is "working" but taking "a full 2 seconds" then my guess is that _something else_ is going on? But as John suggests, we'll need to see the complete .htaccess file. There's not really any such thing as "the fastest .htaccess redirect".

Comment: I have now taken another look. I had thought it was .htaccess, but somewhere along the course prior to this testing, the redirect was removed, so it was Wordpress doing the redirecting.

Comment: Now re-added with cPanel, it's taking .1-.3s to redirect to www. and about .8-1.5s to begin loading resources at www.

Comment: Currently we have this
`
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>
`
But it's not working as intended. It's redirecting the base domain to www correctly (our blog). But not redirecting the forum to www. (mysite.com/forum going straight to mysite.com/forum instead of www.mysite.com/forum)